# While Loop having issues

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to create a function to bucket data into deciles using a different field as the weight so I can have equal exposure buckets.  In doing so I've created a simple example that I'm trying to get into 3 buckets.  I'm really stumbling on the first part of it which is to get this while loop to work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'B': [5,7,9,11,15,19,25,4,3,2]})

bin_size = .333
target_sum = bin_size * df.agg({'B': 'sum'})
increment = 1

bot_try = 0
top_try = 0
c = 0

while (c < target_sum) is True:

    a = df[df['A'] > bot_try]
    b = a[a['A'] <= top_try]
    c = b.agg({'B': 'sum'})
    top_try = top_try + increment

else:

    print(c)
    print(top_try)
```

My results are 0,0.

Thanks!

Comment: Great that you provide your code with an example. What is the expected output for the given example?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
while (c < target_sum) is True:
```

to:

```
while (c < target_sum):
```